# Populate dropdown with for in loop off an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
var myObject = { 3: 'Three', 6: 'Six'};
```

I want to populate those values in a dropdown like so:

```
var statusDropdown = document.createElement('select');
for (var item in myObject ) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = item.value; //this is undfined item = "Three", or "Six" 
    option.value = item.key; //this is undfined item = "Three", or "Six" 
    statusDropdown.options.add(option);
}
```

for in seems the way to go but I am trying to do key and value not just value. This would allow me to set the key to 3 for the first dropdown option, and 6 for second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `for (var item in myObject )`, `item` is the key, and the value will be at `myObject[item]`. So:

```
for (var item in myObject ) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = myObject[item];
    option.value = item; 
    statusDropdown.options.add(option);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of confusing, but `item` actually holds the *key* to the current property, not the actual property itself. Using `myObject[item]` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the code in for loop should be like this.

```
option.text = myObject[item];
option.value = item;
```